# unnest key and value event_params using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

in google big query you can do unnest (key and value) event_params, I get all google event from Big-Query and insert them on MongoDB

how can I select from MongoDB where event_params.key = "firebase_screen_class" haveing value.string_value = "ForceUpdateVC"

i dont need to get any event_params.value.string_value = "ForceUpdateVC" i need only this values if event_params.key = "firebase_screen_class"

any help, please

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa979330af533408048d646"),
    "event_name" : "screen_view",
    "event_params" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "ga_session_id",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : null,
                "int_value" : 1604843171,
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "firebase_previous_class",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : "TrendsScreen",
                "int_value" : null,
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "firebase_screen_class",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : "ForceUpdateVC",
                "int_value" : null,
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "firebase_screen_id",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : null,
                "int_value" : NumberLong(4208934242551216926),
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "firebase_previous_id",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : null,
                "int_value" : NumberLong(4208934242551216925),
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "firebase_event_origin",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : "auto",
                "int_value" : null,
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "ga_session_number",
            "value" : {
                "string_value" : null,
                "int_value" : 49,
                "float_value" : null,
                "double_value" : null
            }
        }
    ],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-11-09T17:15:31.021Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-11-09T17:15:31.021Z")
},
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $elemMatch function on event_params array. It is same as some() function from array.prototype in javascript.
Your query would go like this:
db.collection.find({"event_params":{"$elemMatch": {"key": "firebase_screen_class"}}});

Comment: db.getCollection('events_collection').find({"event_params":{"$elemMatch": {"key": "firebase_screen_class", "value.string_value": "ForceUpdateVC"}}});